# finding the tax value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the tax value which is supposed to be on Line 10: Tax = $.

The codes for tax I am using are

```
x = line6/1000.00
Tax = 0.9x^2 +126.6x - 307.4 
Tax = int(100*Tax + 0.5)/100

If Tax <0 then set Tax = 0.0
```

this is my code

```
def main():
print("IRS Form 1040EZ Tax Computation Program (2015)")
print()
sal = eval(input("Line 1:  Enter wages, salaries, and tips: "))
tint = eval(input("Line 2:  Enter taxable interest: "))
print()
agros = sal + tint
print("Line 4: Adjusted Gross Income: ",agros)
print()
print("Line 5:  Exemption Amount $",10150)
print("Line 6:  Taxable Income: $",agros - 10150)
print()
taxw = eval(input("Line 7:  Enter tax withheld: "))
print()
x = (agros - 10150) / 1000.00
Tax = 0.9,x**+126.6,x - 307.4
Tax = int(100 * Tax, + 0.5) /100
print("Line 10:  Tax = $",Tax)
print()
ref = eval(input("Line 13:  Refund Amount: $"))
print()
owe = eval(input("Line 14:  Amount You Owe: $"))

main()
```

my error is

```
Tax = int(100 * Tax, + 0.5)//100
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Please make sure your code is properly formatted using the formatting tools, and also ensure that it is properly indented to represent your actual code

Comment: Why are there commas in your usage of  `int()` and `Tax` calculation? Why do you even need to cast to an int?

Comment: Also `eval` should probably be replaced with `int` or `float`

Comment: Tax = 0.9,x**+126.6,x - 307.4. This returns a tuple. What actually does this do?

Comment: Tax = 0.9,x**+126.6x-307.4 is the formula to compute Tax

Comment: Try fixing the 2 incorrect `Tax = ...` statements: `Tax = 0.9*x*x + 126.6*x - 307.4`, `Tax = int(100*Tax + 0.5) / 100`.